# Batch rename, add extra "." character at position 3 in filename, recursively

Tags: command-line, regex, batch-rename

I've been struggling to make this work but I am not very good with regex. This is what I tried to do and it didn't work (after 50 minutes, still going on with no visible change):

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do mv $file ${file:0:2}.${file:2}; done
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't appear to be giving anything for `read` to read?

Comment: I created this command from different 'parts' I found on google, I am a newbie and I do not fully understand how this is supposed to work. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The files are named: 01 Song Title.flac and I want them to be named 01. Song Title.flac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One issue you are going to have to face when renaming files in directories recursively is separating the filename (which you want to modify) from the path. You can't simply remove the path component, because then your files will end up being moved rather than simply renamed.

To use your original method, I think you'd need to do something like

```
while read -r -d '' f; do 
  file="${f##*/}"; path="${f%/*}" 
  echo mv -- "$path/$file" "$path/${file:0:2}"."${file:2}"
done < <(find -type f -iname "*.wav" -print0)
```

---

Another option is to use the `find` command's `-execdir` instead of `-exec`. I *think* it's safe to assume that the results will get presented to your rename command (whether you use `rename` or `mv`) with just a leading `./` as the path, in which case you can do

```
find -type f -iname "*.wav" -execdir rename -nv -- 's|\./..|$&.|' {} +
```

or using a more perl-ish variant

```
find -type f -iname "*.wav" -execdir rename -nv -- 's|\./..\K|.|' {} +
```

or using something more equivalent to your original `mv` approach

```
find -type f -iname "*.wav" -execdir bash -c 'echo mv -- "$0" "${0:0:4}"."${0:4}"' {} \;
```

(note that the substring indices have been increased by 2 to allow for the leading `./` path component).

If your version of `find` doesn't have the `-execdir` option, you could modify the `rename` regex to skip the longest matching path prefix, e.g.

```
find -type f -iname "*.wav" -exec rename -nv -- 's|.*/..\K|.|' {} +
```

Note: these expressions all have "no-op" switches in them (either rename's `-n` option, or an `echo` command) so that you can verify what they *would* do before committing.

Comment: find . -type f -iname "*.wav" -execdir bash -c 'mv -- "$0" "${0:0:4}"."${0:4}"' {} \; solved it, none of the other versions found on this thread worked. Congratulations and thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done using `rename`:

```bsh
rename 's/ /\./' file.txt
```

Example:

```bsh
$ ls -l
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 0 Mar 30 04:22 01 Song Title.flac
$ rename 's/ /\./' 01\ Song\ Title.flac 
$ ls -l
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 0 Mar 30 04:22 01.Song Title.flac
```

**EDIT:** If you want a space after `01.`:

```bsh
rename 's/ /\. /' file.txt
```

If you want all the files under the directory `/directory/to/search` and under all its subdirectories having extension `.wav` renamed as expected, try this:

```
find /directory/to/search -type f -name "*.wav" -execdir rename 's/(^\d+) /$1. /' {} +
```

To become case insensitive:

```
find /directory/to/search -type f -iname "*.wav" -execdir rename 's/(^\d+) /$1. /' {} +
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22417/discussion-on-answer-by-heemayl-batch-rename-add-extra-character-at-positio).

Answer (score 0):

This works (tested):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

filenames=$(find . -type f) # stores all filenames in $filenames
for filename in $filenames; do # for each member in $filenames
    newfilename=$(echo "$filename" | sed 's/\(.*\)\/\(..\)\(.*\)$/\1\/\2\.\3/') # edits $filename by adding a . after the second character and stores the edited string in $newfilename
    mv "$filename" "$newfilename" # renames $filename to $newfilename
done
```